# How to get object value if key is not string but you are given string key to find value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

**How to get value of Object if its key is not string but you are given a string to find value**

```
Example: let obj={ arr: ["Kapil"]};
         

         find value of obj.arr is you are given 'arr' as a key
```

I know this seems stupid to use obj.'arr' but it gave me undefined.

Is there anyway to solve this problem

Any help will be highly commended

Comment: I think it wants you to use the square bracket notation probably? try `obj['arr']`

Comment: Thank You WillD, Yeah it worked. Didn't know before that we can access the value of an object like this :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use square bracket to access it `obj['arr']`

Answer (score 0):

Lodash if you don't mind.

```js
const obj = { arr: ["Kapil"] };

console.log(_.get(obj, "arr"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```